# Importing planet-latest.osm.pbf into nominatim is slow

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, nominatim

is it normal that my server is importing the planet-latest.osm.pbf at the following rate?

Processing: Node(1008470k 238.8k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)

According to this the total node count is 4 billion and im at the above value after three days. So the process on importing takes more than weeks...

I am using the following command:
`sudo ./utils/setup.php --osm-file ../data/planet-latest.osm.pbf --all --osm2pgsql-cache 32000 2>&1 | tee setup.log`

Server specs are:

```
Intel Core i7-3770
2x HDD SATA 4,0 TB Enterprise
4x RAM 8192 MB DDR3
```

Postgre Tuning settings are:

```
shared_buffers (2GB)
maintenance_work_mem (10GB)
work_mem (50MB)
effective_cache_size (24GB)
synchronous_commit = off
checkpoint_segments = 100 # only for postgresql <= 9.4
checkpoint_timeout = 10min
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
```

Can I speed up the process?

PS: What does k mean? 1k = 1000 Nodes?

Comment: The reason for the poor performance is your magnetic device. Get a SSD. Also the amount of RAM is pretty low for importing the whole planet. Alternatively try a smaller extract first.

Comment: @scai can I do an async import afterwards or is the db blocked while update.php is running?

Comment: What exactly is an async import? I don't think you can run multiple updates in parallel, this can't work.

Comment: My question was if I could import another .pbf file while accessing the existing database data. Or will the database be blocked while the import-process?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I still doubt it. And it will probably reduce your performance even more.